# Powershell script is not working when called within Jenkins pipeline

Tags: powershell, jenkins, groovy

I've a simple powershell script that calls a program which runs in full screen mode with some input parameters. If I run the script locally it's working fine but when it's called within Jenkins pipeline, getting this results.txt file is not found which is only created if the program ran successfully but what I've noticed is that the command itself is not get executed so the program doesn't run.

I've changed the syntax of how the script is called like &, Start-Process, single quotes, double quotes and whatever I could think of have tried but same failure, the program doesn't run.

I'm not able to figure out what would be the correct way to call this script inside pipeline script.

I've a script repo which I checkout and the script files are checked out at workspace, the app program is installed in C:\Program Files\app
I've tested with environment variable set and not set but no luck.

*powershell script:*

```
// dir = C:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\scripts
$dir = Get-Location
$app = "C:\Program Files\app\"

Copy-Item ".\app.xml" -destination $app

Set-Location $app

Write-Output "After setting path to..."
$PWD.Path

if(Test-Path ".\result.xml"){
    Remove-Item ".\result.xml" #Remove previous result if exist
}

Write-Output "Path should be app"
$PWD.Path

.\app.exe /max --definition=app.xml --online=off --export=result.xml
```

*Jenkins:*

```
stage ("Run app") {
    buildDir = "C:\\Jenkins\\workspace"
    environment {
        SCRIPTDIR = "${buildDir}\\scripts"
    }
    steps {
        script {
            node("appNode"){
                def scriptDir = "C:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\scripts"
               
                dir (scriptDir) {
                    def output = powershell(returnStdout: true, script:"""powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File $env.SCRIPTDIR\\app.ps1""")
                    println("debug $output")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Error:*

```
21:03:56  java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Jenkins\workspace\scripts\Results.txt
21:03:56    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
21:03:56    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
21:03:56    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
21:03:56    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:235)
21:03:56    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:371)
21:03:56    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:422)
21:03:56    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:420)
21:03:56    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:156)
21:03:56    at hudson.FilePath.newInputStreamDenyingSymlinkAsNeeded(FilePath.java:2122)
21:03:56    at hudson.FilePath$Read.invoke(FilePath.java:2204)
21:03:56    at hudson.FilePath$Read.invoke(FilePath.java:2191)
21:03:56    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3329)
21:03:56    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
21:03:56    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
21:03:56    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:375)
21:03:56    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:73)
21:03:56    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
21:03:56    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
21:03:56    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
21:03:56    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:118)
21:03:56    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
21:03:56  Caused: java.io.IOException
21:03:56    at hudson.remoting.FastPipedInputStream.read(FastPipedInputStream.java:170)
21:03:56    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
21:03:56    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
21:03:56    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
21:03:56    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
21:03:56    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
21:03:56    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1432)
21:03:56    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1411)
21:03:56    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1208)
21:03:56    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1022)
21:03:56    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:2839)
21:03:56    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:2865)
21:03:56    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.ReadFileStep$Execution.run(ReadFileStep.java:108)
21:03:56    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.ReadFileStep$Execution.run(ReadFileStep.java:94)
21:03:56    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
21:03:56    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
21:03:56    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
21:03:56    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
21:03:56    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
21:03:56    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
21:03:56  Finished: FAILURE
```

'''

Comment: What is the output of the PowerShell script logged by Jenkins?

Comment: Powershell's got `.\result.xml`, but error's got `C:\Jenkins\workspace\scripts\Results.txt`?